# dynamically resize iframe height based on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, dynamic, height

First, I'll give you the structure of my page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
    <iframe>
        <div id="div1">
        </div>
    </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If only I knew ahead the size of `div1`, there's no problem here. However, I am dynamically adding contents into `div1` using jquery ajax and so I could not pre-set the `<iframe>`'s height.

I've tried the solutions I found in other threads by adding some script in the `onload` of the `<iframe>` but it's useless since the contents are dynamically changing without reloading the page.

Any help?

Comment: since you are changing the content of div1, can you calculate the height of div1 after each change, then change the height of the iframe

Comment: Even if I can calculate the height of div1, how would I change the height of the iframe? I can't do it with simple jquery and I don't want to delve so much into complex javascript.

Comment: where is the code that changes the content at/ is it in the iframe or in the parent?

Comment: @Huangism I don't know if this is what your looking for but the code that changes the content is an ajax call. Something like `$('div').html(data)` at the success function of `$.ajax`.

Comment: Is that ajax in the parent page, or in the iframe src page?

Comment: Why are you changing the content of a `div` in an `iframe` instead of changing the content of the outer `div` that the `iframe` is in?

Comment: @Huangism inside the iframe
@millimoose because it is in that `div` (inside that iframe) where the data is being loaded.

i think i'll stop using iframe here. It's such a pain in the behind.

Answer (score 3):

In your child page, after the dynamically generated code has finished loading, insert this code:

```
// Rsize containing iframe to proper height
parent.parent.resizeIframe($('html').height());
```

Then, in the parent page, include this function:

```
function resizeIframe(newHgt)
{
    $('#iframeid').height((parseInt(newHgt)+75)+'px');
}
```

This will get you where you need to be, but the issue I'm trying to resolve is how to determine the size of the iframe contents *after* the dynamically generated code has finished loading ... "all from the parent page".

Anyway, hope this helps you.

...

Comment: You should open a question for your issue.

Comment: Should mention that this does not work when same-origin policy is in affect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use an iframe here. But maybe you cantry using

http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing

Comment: I've actually used that script already and it did not solved my problem. I'm now redesigning my app to get rid of the `iframe`. It had wasted me so much time fixing a lot of things.

Thanks to all your replies.